# the user who have post should only able to edit blog below code correct but is this professional approach

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

below is my code inside views.py. Here i don't required but what one should do if he also want staff member to allow update

```
@method_decorator(login_required(login_url='login'), name='dispatch')
        class PostUpdate(UpdateView):
            model = Post
            form_class = PostForm
            template_name = 'blog/post_form.html'
        
            def get_queryset(self):
                return super(PostUpdate, self).get_queryset().filter(user=self.request.user)
        
            def get_success_url(self):
                return reverse('dashboard')
```

Comment: Use an if-else condition...

Comment: inside get_queryset?

Comment: yes `if request.user.is_staff:    return <unfiltered_queryset>`, `else: return <filtered_queryset>`

Comment: i use same logic in deleteview but it didn't work    
        if self.request.user.is_staff:
            return super(PostDelete, self).get_queryset()       showing error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'filter

Answer (score 0):

You can write an owner mixin, as you check if the user is logged in, you can check if object.owner is equal to the user.
btw check object-level permission but decorating get_object method.

Comment: If you format your answer it'll be easier for everyone to read & understand id.